# Laravel Eloquent Query With Between And Just Month And Day

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a date in the datatabase like this:  **`2019-08-28`**

I need to make a query where I can select the rows between two dates BUT just filtering the month and the day. I have this:

```
 $session_data = $request->session()->all();

 $date1 = date('Y-m-d');
 $date2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date1. ' + 4 days'));

 $employees = Employee::whereBetween('born_date', array($date1, $date2))->take(4)->get();
```

but this selects does not work because it is filtering with the year..i need something which it uses this:

```
'DAY(born_date) = '. date('d')
'MONTH(born_date) = '. date('m'))
```

But I do not know how to add this with between.. Thanks

Comment: I posted an answer given you guidance to use two helpful methods, I'd want to provide a exact answer but your use case isn't very clear at the moment. If you need more help try updating your question including a better explanation or a clearer example. Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel has [helpful `whereXYZ()` methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses) to filter by day/month/year/time.

You can filter by a given month:

```
/*
| 
| Get all the employees that were born between
| june and december of any year in your db
| 
*/
$employees = Employee::whereMonth('born_date', '>=', 6)->get();
```

or make a filter by day:

```
/*
|
| Get all the employees that were born between the
| 1st and the 10th of every month of every year
|
*/
$employees = Employee::whereDay('born_date', '=<', 10)->get();
```

Of course you can combine this methods to accomplish your desired output.

Comment: Much cleaner to use the methods specifically built into Eloquent than to mess with the raw SQL - it's where Laravel really shines.

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below

```
$employees = Employee::whereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(born_date, '%m%d') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m%d') AND DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 DAY), '%m%d')")->take(4)->get();
```

The idea is to format dates as %m%d and compare these values